# Can we use both serilog and nlog in same dot net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, nlog, serilog

I am trying to use both serilog and nlog in my web app. But only serilog logs are logged to the file.
Nlog file is created but logs not logged.

Is it possible to use both or not?

Comment: There is no problem with them working side by side. However there are specific things that happen in specific places - i.e. you can bing the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` output to one or the other. You have not gone very far into describing what you've tried, what you expect to happen or what you want to change about that. I would say in general [you do want to work toward having one logger over time though](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DefaultTrialRetire.html).

Comment: Yes, but it depends. This question is missing some details/is too broad.